# Why Pakistan can "flatten the curve" but India can't?

Tags: covid-19, epidemiology

Comparing the Covid 19 trends between [India](https://covid19.who.int/region/searo/country/in) and [Pakistan](https://covid19.who.int/region/emro/country/pk):

[image: India Covid 19 new cases on weekly basis]

[image: Pakistan Covid 19 new cases on weekly basis]

One can immediately notice the stark difference: Pakistan managed to "flatten the curve", and India is unable to control the outbreak at all.

Why such a difference?

Recall that:

1. They are geographical neighbors, which means that the climate, humidity and everything that can affect the survivability of the virus inside human body remains the same
2. The [demographics between the two countries are similar](https://www.indexmundi.com/factbook/compare/india.pakistan/demographics). So both should be equally susceptible to the attack of Covid 19.
3. Both don't regulate the information flow unlike North Korea for example.
4. Both are poor countries with similar income levels and sanitization condition.
5. And India should have no problem in copying whatever successful intervention that Pakistan introduces.
6. What about the falling levels of testing in Pakistan? Maybe it can explain some drop in the newly discovered cases, but it definitely can't explain all. As per BBC news, ["*but the recorded drop in infections is substantiated by the fact that the proportion of tests that come back as positive has also been decreasing, as have hospital admissions.*"](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-53742214)
7. The above article offers a theory: *there are more large, densely populated cities in India, so infections had levelled off in both Mumbai and Delhi, but were increasing in other parts of the country.* But this theory fails to explain why other neighboring, smaller countries like [Nepal](https://covid19.who.int/region/searo/country/np) and [Bangladesh](https://covid19.who.int/region/searo/country/bd) fail to replicate the success of Pakistan.

So why Pakistan can "flatten the curve" but India (and other South Area countries) can't?

Comment: In retrospect, it looks like India actually did a much better job of flattening the curve after this question was posted. But seven months later, India has completely lost control of the situation and Pakistan isn't doing so great either. I think this shows why questions like this involving all sorts of social, political, and economic variables don't yield good answers on science-based forums. This is why I'm closing as opinion based.